# Powershell -Recurse Parameter; How to exclude specific subdirectory

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script that changes file extensions and etc, after it copies files from dev to the root folder. I already successfully copy the files. However, I am stuck between using -Recurse which applies to all sub folders( I want to exclude dev folder), or only applying the code the eoot folder.

CODE:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command "$w = $args[0];foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path "$w" -Exclude *.bat, *.txt, *.png, *.jpg, *.jpeg, *.gif, *.mp3, *.mp4, dev\\*) {"$w+$file";(Get-Content $w$file).replace('dev/', '') | Set-Content "$w$file";(Get-Content $w$file).replace('.min.js', '.minjs') | Set-Content "$w$file";(Get-Content $w$file).replace('.json', '.xson') | Set-Content "$w$file";(Get-Content $w$file).replace('https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', '/httpswgacanalyticsjs/') | Set-Content "$w$file";(Get-Content $w$file).replace('.js', '.min.js') | Set-Content "$w$file";(Get-Content $w$file).replace('.minjs', '.min.js') | Set-Content "$w$file";(Get-Content $w$file).replace('.xson', '.json') | Set-Content "$w$file";(Get-Content $w$file).replace('/httpswgacanalyticsjs/', 'https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js') | Set-Content "$w$file";(Get-Content $w$file).replace('.min.css', '.mincss') | Set-Content "$w$file";(Get-Content $w$file).replace('.css', '.min.css') | Set-Content "$w$file";(Get-Content $w$file).replace('.mincss', '.min.css') | Set-Content "$w$file";};Write-Host ".""" "%path%"
```

INPUT:

```
FOLDER
    -> dev
        ->files
        ->folders
```

OUTPUT:

```
FOLDER
    -> dev        //exclude
        ->files   //exclude
        ->folders //exclude
    ->files //execute code on this
        ->folders //execute code on this
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try Something like this (PowerShell v5 for use -file option)

```
$w = "c:\temp\";
$exclude=@("*.bat", "*.txt", "*.png", "*.jpg", "*.jpeg", "*.gif", "*.mp3", "*.mp4")

$hashreplace = @{}
$hashreplace.'dev/'= ''
$hashreplace.'.min.js'= '.minjs'
$hashreplace.'.json'= '.xson'
$hashreplace.'https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js'= '/httpswgacanalyticsjs/'
$hashreplace.'.js'= '.min.js'
$hashreplace.'.minjs'= '.min.js'
$hashreplace.'.xson'= '.json'
$hashreplace.'/httpswgacanalyticsjs/'= 'https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js'
$hashreplace.'.min.css'= '.mincss'
$hashreplace.'.css'= '.min.css'
$hashreplace.'.mincss'= '.min.css'

foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -Path "$w" -Exclude $exclude | where {$_.fullname -notlike "*\dev\*"}) 
{
    $text=(Get-Content $file.FullName)
    $hashreplace.Keys | %{ $text = $text.Replace($_, $hashreplace[$_])}
    $text | set-content $file.FullName 
};
```

Comment: How would I start this Powershell file from a batch file? I can't see to get it to work because their is a space in the path. Additionally how do I input an argument?

Comment: powershell -executionPolicy bypass -noexit -file "c:\temp\path with space\test.ps1" "argument"

Comment: After, much trial and error, the where statement was missing asterisks here  "*\dev\*". Thanks for the help, it is now functioning.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this so I'm solely going off theory however the following may help from what I understand you are trying to do.

Add in something like:

```
$filesToRecurse = Get-ChildItem -Path {pathToFileToRecurse} -Exclude {pathToFolderToExclude} | where {! $_.PSIsContainer}
```

Then use the $filesToRecurse variable for the list of files to perform the rename on, as it will not contain the files or folders you wish to exclude.

Note: You can also create and use an array variable if you want to exclude multiple locations, etc.